# .htaccess redirect all urls using %20 to -

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, replace

I had a problem with duplicated urls, like:

```
/term/this-is-the-term
/term/this%20is%20the%20term
```

Which I already solved by making sure all the links use the `-` instead,

Now I want to redirect any indexed url with `%20` so the problem disappears from Google webmasters (and is actually solved)

How can I redirect any url using `%20` to `-` ?

I know basics of simple redirections but I smell this can only be achieved using a regex, which I am not so familiar with,

Any hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\ (.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

That redirects anything with a space (%20) to use a dash instead. You'll need to put that rule *before* any other rules you have in the htaccess file in your document root (or in whatever directory you want this to apply to).

To have this apply to your query string (everything after the `?`) you need to do something special:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)%20(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1-%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: But using rewrite will actually redirect to the other url? or it will only read it as so? -EDIT- I'm trying ant this url is not being redirected:  `/term/?search=cocinar&termtext=queso cheddar`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet It will redirect the URI. What you have there is part of the **query string**, and that needs its own special rule

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way of doing this is:

```
Redirect 301 "/term/this is the term" "http://yourdomain.com/term/this-is-the-term"
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. First, change the %20 to a literal space in the URL slugs by clicking spacebar on your keyboard wherever there is a %20 in the link. Then, wrap the entire URL slug in quotes. This works for me, too. This article talks more about a single 301 rediret with spaces in the URL slug too: https://designertofullstack.com/htaccess-301-redirect-for-a-url-with-spaces/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one single rule that **will replace ALL the spaces with hyphens whether spaces are in query string OR in URI:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^%20]*)%20([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R]
```

Comment: Did you try: `/term/this%20is%20the%20term` OR `/term/?search=cocinar&termtext=queso cheddar` ?

Comment: I just retested this code with both these URLs and got all spaces replaced by hyphens. Do you have some other rules also in your .htaccess?